# How do I make my sidebar appear at the bottom of my responsive webpage?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tumblr, sidebar

First time on these boards, so please go easy.

I've been trying to make my website http://sartorialequity.com/ responsive by using media queries. However, my right sidebar is currently displayed above my content, while I'd like it to appear at the bottom of my content.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#container {
            width: 960px; 
            margin: auto;
        }

#content {
            width: 66.67%; 
        }

#sidebar {
            width: 260px;
            float: right;
            top: 70px; 
            position: relative;
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#container {
width: 91%
        }

#content {
float: none;
width: auto;
line-height: 135%;
       }

#sidebar {
float: none;
width: auto;
top: 10px;
       }

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

The solutions I've tried so far:

**1. Using display: table-footer-group**

```
#content-sidebar-wrap {display:table;}
#content {display:table-header-group; float: none; width: auto}
#sidebar {display:table-footer-group; float: none; width: auto}
```

On a mobile phone, this was successful in getting the sidebar to appear below the content, at least on the main page. However, it caused the content and sidebar of PermaLink Pages to extend beyond the width of the header.

**2. Rearranging div id="sidebar" and div id="content"**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

On a mobile phone, this was successful in getting the sidebar to appear below the content. However, when on my PC's browser window, it caused the sidebar to appear at the bottom of the page.

I'd truly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Be specific.....On the PC what do you want? and On the mobile what do you want?

Comment: Your HTML indicates that `#content` and `#sidebar` and not inside `#container` - is this accurate? It might be worth putting this into JSFiddle so we can see what works and what doesn't with the actual code.

Comment: @Toby, why do you need jsfiddle?.... while he has given the address of his website.

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar I have no idea if the code above is correct, and/or identical to the code on his website. I've assumed before, and it's only caused further confusion.

Comment: By the way, right sidebar is on the right side. In mobile it's completely gone. Then what is your requirement? @ M. Lai

Comment: @Toby, my apologies, #container should include #content and #sidebar. I've made the adjustment to the code above

Comment: @Shudhansh Shekhar, I would like for the sidebar to appear below the content in mobile. Currently it appears above the content

Comment: When people link to a version of their website with an issue on SO, they usually update their site at some point, so the version of the link becomes obsolete. With jsfiddle the code is preserved and can be versioned by anyone. Much much better than a site link.

Answer (score 0):

Content appearance is not merely concerned with the order of your raw html. Styles can bring a lot of change. 
First try to use this layout:

```
<div id="content"></div> // Content div comes first 
 <div id="sidebar"></div> // Then Comes Sidebar.
```

Remember,  this layout does not mean you may not use your sidebar right to your page. If `content` div is not floated, `sidebar` will come after `content` and at the bottom of page, float to right. So, you have to float the `content` div to left, this will cause a space of 33.3334% to it's right, that will be filled up by `sidebar`.
But for mobile device, since you have set `float:none` to both divs, the order of raw html will itself play the role for appearing sidebar to bottom.
 
Hence, try some minor style changes:

```
    #content {
    float: left; //This line will bring the change. It is necessary.
    width: 66.67%;
    width: calc(100% - 294px); //you may or may not add this line 
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Georgia, Palatino, 'Palatino Linotype', Times, 'Times New    Roman', serif;
    line-height: 160%;
}
```

Comment: @Shdhansh Shekhar, thanks for your help! The critical element was float: left and positioning div id="content" above div id="sidebar". Thanks again and cheers

Answer (score -1):

The content `div` should be first in the markup. That would solve the issue you have.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```